# while importing unsigned column in phpmyadmin getting 0.00

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, import-from-excel

i was importing csv file in phpmyadmin. i have set of columns. in csv file i have negative vlaues(-154.98)(data tyoe- decimal) but in mysql i don't want that negative sign. i already fixed that column as unsigned.but i am getting 0.00.but expected as 154.98.

[image]  [image]

[image]

can any one please help me on this. i want to get those all values without negative sign.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is to load the data into a *signed* column.  Then fix the sign:

```
update t
    set col = - col
    where col < 0;
```

If you like, you can modify the type after you have fixed the data.

You are getting `0.00` because negative values are not allowed.  MySQL does not remove the minus sign, just because the value is not allowed.